# Why threads are not working simultaneously?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

For starters i'm new in Python.

I will be brief. I'm trying to fetch all links from the website using threads.

The problem is that threads are waiting for their turn, but I want them to work simultaneously with other threads.

For example, I set the number of threads to **2**, and then get **2** chunks with links. 
I want the first thread to iterate over the links in the first chunk, and the second thread to iterate over the links in the second chunk **SIMULTANEOUSLY**.  But my program works in such a way that threads are waiting for their turn. What am I doing wrong, guys? Much obliged for your help

**My code:**

**target()**

```
def url_target(text, e):
    global links
    global chunks

    number = int(sys.argv[1])
    for m in text:
        time.sleep(0.2)
        print(m, e)
    print('\n')
```

**main()**

```
def main():
global links
global chunks

url = sys.argv[2]
links = fetch_links(url)
number = int(sys.argv[1])
url_chunk = len(links) // number
start, stop = 0, url_chunk + len(links) % number
chunks = []

time.sleep(1)

while start < len(links):
    for i in range(number):
        part_links = links[start:stop]
        p = Thread(name='myThread', target=url_target, args=(part_links, i+1))
        p.start()    
        chunks.append(p)
        start, stop = stop, stop + url_chunk
        p.join()

time.sleep(1)
while chunks:
    d = chunks.pop()
    print(f'{d.ident} done')
```

Thanks! I'd appreciate any help you can give!

Comment: `p.join()` blocks until `p` completes, so you only have one thread running at a time, and only at that point does the loop continue to start the next thread.

Comment: How big is this site? Threading/processes have a lot of overhead, so it'd need to be massive for any of this to pay off. I'd suggest doing it single threaded. Doing multiple requests is something you could parallelize, though, since the thread sits idle off the CPU. CPython is basically single threaded thanks to the global interpreter lock, so if you're doing blocking, CPU-bound work, you can't paralellize it. I'm not sure why you'd want to multithread printing in any case--it'll just randomly interleave the results.

Comment: @chepner Hi! Thank you for answering me! So what do I need to do, move join() to another line? Did I place join() on the wrong line? Or should I remove it?

Comment: @ggorlen Hi! Honestly, this is not one specific website. From 90 to 800 links. I want to get all these links from the website as fast as possible. So i thought 'hmm, i think i need to use threads'.

Comment: @Slayer598 first, python implements a GIL, so unless you're using the multiprocessing module only one thread is really running at a time anyway regardless of your using join to block. Two, I/O bound tasks will generally benefit more from using asyncio and libraries atop it like aiohttp.

Comment: 90 to 800 links is not many, depending on the size of the file. Python can get it single threaded almost instantly, so I'm pretty sure any HTML files under (wildly ballparking) 5 megs are going to be parsed and extracted plenty fast in one thread with beautifulsoup. From your code, it's not clear that you've implemented it single threaded yet. I'd do that first and then check if there's a performance problem. If there is, you're best bet is to go multiprocessing. If you have multiple websites, request those in parallel (asyncio is best here as Jared mentions).

Comment: @JaredSmith, the GIL probably is not an issue in this case. The GIL only prevents threads from executing Python code in parallel. But in this program (whenever the OP finally gets it right) There will be several threads _waiting_ in parallel for responses from web servers. The GIL does _not_ prevent multiple threads from awaiting the completion of I/O at the same time.

Comment: @SolomonSlow right, although I stand by the assertion that asyncio is a better fit than threads for this.

Answer (score 0):

`p.join()` blocks until `p` completes. You want to start all the threads first, *then* wait on each in turn.

```
while start < len(links):
    for i in range(number):
        part_links = links[start:stop]
        p = Thread(name='myThread', target=url_target, args=(part_links, i+1))
        p.start()    
        chunks.append(p)
        start, stop = stop, stop + url_chunk

time.sleep(1)
for p in chunks:
    p.join()
```

If you aren't planning on doing anything while waiting for all the threads to complete, this is fine. However, you might want to block until *any* thread completes, rather than an arbitrarily chosen one. A thread pool can help, but
a simple way to implement a thread pool is to wait for a short period of time for a thread to complete. If it doesn't, wait on another one and come back to the first one later. For example,

```
from collections import deque

chunks = deque()

for start in range(0, len(links), url_chunk):
    for i in range(1, number+1):
        part_links = links[start:start + url_chunk]
        p = Thread(name='myThread', target=url_target, args=(part_links, i))
        p.start()
        chunks.append(p)

while chunks:
    p = chunks.popleft()
    p.join(5)  # Wait 5 seconds, or some other small period of time
    if p.is_alive():
        chunks.append(p)  # put it back
```

Comment: Hi again! I do  as you show me, but for some reason links just...duplicate, and that's it. That's strange... And 'deque()' not working. As soon as i change empty list 'chunks = []' to deque 'chunks = deque()', i just can't call method join(). I jus't don't know why it works like that. I do EXACTLY as you show me in this 'code chunk'